# Hypotheses in search of hypotheses tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, experiment-design

I am searching for an efficient way of testing a set of hypotheses. I have not yet run the study in question, but I want to have a clear analytic plan in advance.

### The experimental set-up:

Individuals state their opinion at t1 in response to a vignette.

At t2, Individuals are exposed to a 2x2 design which alters the vignette. The altered vignette is presented again and the individuals' opinion is asked again.

In both cases, individuals state their opinion with a 7-point likert scale.

### The hypotheses:

Factor A (A0, A1) is supposed to affect responses at t2 depending on responses at t1. Negative responses are more strongly negative in the A1 condition and positive responses are more positive in the A1 condition.

Yet, this behaviour is supposed to depend on the presence or absence of Factor B (B0, B1). For individuals in condition B0, A1 should not have the effect of polarising opinion. Yet, in condition B1, A1 should act as expected.

Therefore the following should hold:

1. A0/B0 : No opinion change
2. A1/B0 : No opinion change
3. A0/B1 : No opinion change
4. A1/B1 : Opinion polarisation

### The model

However, I am unsure how to test these hypotheses given that I am not so much interested in *mean changes*, but in *mean changes across responses at t1*.

I have considered a linear model interacting Factor A, B and response at t1. But I am unsure if such a model would really answer my question. Furthermore I am afraid that it will be impossible to accurately power such a three-way interaction.

Is there maybe a much more simple method, I am completely missing here?

Comment: What measurements do you use, i.e., what are the values the responses can take? Would you want to treat them as quantitative?

Comment: It's a 7-point likert scale. For simplicity, I think it would be best to just assume that it's truly metric

Comment: Standard linear model analysis will in fact treat mean changes, and nothing like opinion polarisation. When testing, you need null and alternative hypotheses. "No change" seems to be a sensible null hypothesis for all four combinations. However A1/B1 requires a specific alternative. Do you want to test the other three against the same alternative, or against mean change, or something else?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's simple. It is probably doable, but it rather looks like a full advisory project, meaning that it is probably too much effort to just suggest something on cross-validated. By the way I can well imagine issues with the "metric" assumption; chances are there are floor and ceiling effects, i.e., there cannot be a change down from 1 or a change up from 7, which may create trouble for a metric approach.

Comment: I see, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I guess the design needs major revisions.